# Different Fields Multiplication in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can we multiple two different fields from different collections in mongoDB?

any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: i would like to know it too.

Comment: Yes we can. We join two collections with ´$lookup´ and multiply fields

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using the Aggregation Pipeline $multiply operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/

What you want to do is join two collections together using $lookup https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/.  In this case, I'll join the `accounts` and `transactions` collections on the `account_id` field.

Then we can project the fields we want to multiply.  In this case, I'm getting the first element in the `account` array, which represents the `account` document I'm joining from the `accounts` collection.

Finally, I can multiply the two fields together.

```
[{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'accounts',
        localField: 'account_id',
        foreignField: 'account_id',
        as: 'account'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        account: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$account", 0]
        },
        transaction_count: "$transaction_count",
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        product: {
            $multiply: ["$transaction_count", "$account.limit"]
        }
    }
}]
```

To reproduce my solution above, create a free cluster in Atlas (https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) and then load the sample data.  Navigate to the Cluster's Collections.  Then navigate to the `sample_analytics` database and the `transactions` collection.  Then navigate to the `Aggregation` tab.  Here you can create an Aggregation Pipeline stage by stage.  It's incredibly helpful so you can see the output of each stage as you build the next.  Below is a screenshot of the Aggregation Pipeline I described in my solution above.

[image: Aggregation Pipeline]

If you don't have experience with the Aggregation Pipeline, I highly recommend MongoDB University's free course: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB aggregation operations allows us join two collections with `$lookup` method and compute field operation (i.e `$multiply`)

### Given

```
"collection": [
    {
      id: 1,
      "total": 5
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      "total": 2
    }
  ],
  "collection2": [
    {
      collId: 1,
      "total": 3
    },
    {
      collId: 2,
      "total": 4
    }
  ]
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      let: {
        col_id: "$id",
        col_total: "$total",

      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$collId",
                "$$col_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            summary: {
              $multiply: [
                "$total",
                "$$col_total"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "result"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      result: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            tmp: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$result",
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          in: "$$tmp.summary"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3d1CYIzI4eP)

### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1,
    "result": 15,
    "total": 5
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "id": 2,
    "result": 8,
    "total": 2
  }
]
```